# Configure Samba server via command line Linux CentOS

Tags: windows, linux, samba

I am trying to get samba working on centOS... I installed it via Yum, changed the samba config file to:

```
[ShareName]
        path = /var/www/html/
        public = no
        writable = yes
        printable = no
        create mask = 0765
        valid users = username
```

Restarted samba and it did nothing.. the windows network is not seeing the share at all. I realize there is most likely something I am missing but I have always done it with the GUI, but unable to do that this time.. Any pointers?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `testparm -v` to test and see the parameters. Maybe `browsable` is set to `no`.

Comment: It only shows

 path = /var/www/html/
        read only = No
        guest ok = Yes

Comment: But even if I add new params and restart smb, it doesn't take

Answer (score 1):

To configure the server:

```
mkdir /samba
chmod a+w /samba
yum install samba -y
vim /etc/samba/smb.conf
```

Content:

```
[public]
comment = Only users
path = /samba
public = yes
browseable=yes
writable = yes
printable = no
write list = +staff
```

finally:

```
service smb restart
```

Possible permissions:

- `browseable=yes` ->we CAN see the shared dir
- `browseable=no` -> we CANNOT see the shared dir
- `public=yes`    ->Allows anonymous Login
- `public=no`     ->Stops  anonymous Login
- `writable = no`     ->uploading is denied  for BOTH the users.
- `writable = yes`    ->uploading is allowed for BOTH the users
- `hosts allow=192.168.0.20` ->Allow only 192.168.0.20 ip to access share, other ips are denied

Client commands:

- `smbclient -L //192.168.0.48/share`  ->List directories shared
- `smbclient //192.168.0.48/share`   ->Anonymous Login
- `smbclient //192.168.0.48/share -U u1`  ->Non Anonymous Login
- `get <file>`
- `put <file>`

[Source](http://www.redhatlinux.info/2011/11/configure-samba-server.html)

Answer (score 0):

Tried adding

> browseable = yes

Under *valid users* ?